# LINQ to SQL in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: c#, linq

What is LINQ for following SQL query for selecting NULL values from ParentCategoryID column:

```
SELECT ID, CategoryName, ParentCategoryID FROM Category 
WHERE (ParentCategoryID IS NULL)
```

I have try following LINQ but doesn't work:

```
from u in db.Categories 
where (u.ParentCategoryID == null) 
select u
```

Comment: Have you tried to write such a LINQ statement yet?  Show your code.  In what way does your code not work?

Answer (score 0):

make some class, containing fields, those you select (Class1)

```
List<Class1> list = CategoryRepository.Categories
                        .Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId != null)
                        .Select(x => new Class1(x.CategoryName, x.ParentCategoryId)
                        .ToList();
```